# How to show newline \n of array in -(NSString *)description method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I'm a new programmer following the iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide Chapter 2 - Gold Challenge.

I have a class `BNRItem`. And a subclass of `BNRItem`, `BNRContainer`.

My `BNRContainer` contains 11 items. The first ten items are `BNRItems`. The 11th item is another `BNRContainer` also containing ten items.

In main.m:

```
NSLog(@"%@", container);
```

In BNRContainer.m:

```
- (NSString *)description
{
    NSString *descriptionString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: Total Value = $%d: %@", [self containerName], [self valueInDollars], subItems];
    return descriptionString;
}
```

subItems is a pointer to NSMutableArray which holds all my BNRItems which I want to print out:

```
@interface BNRContainer : BNRItem
{
    NSString *containerName;
    NSMutableArray *subItems;
}
```

What is printed out:

```
My Container contains 11 items
My Container: Total Value = $1096: (
    "Undead Goblin (8Q2U8): Worth $73, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Flaming Troll (5Y2V3): Worth $40, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Undead Human (2F9Z7): Worth $40, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Flying Elf (8G5V6): Worth $99, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Undead Orc (3P9B1): Worth $10, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Undead Goblin (6R5C1): Worth $93, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Stone Giant (3E4O0): Worth $1, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Stone Goblin (3A6T4): Worth $30, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Shiny Troll (8S3I1): Worth $77, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Flying Orc (4F6F9): Worth $65, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Dublicate Container: Total Value = $568: (\n    \"Flying Elf (1P5F4): Worth $29, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",\n    \"Shiny Elf (3R2Q6): Worth $88, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",\n    \"Shiny Dwarf (4X7P8): Worth $38, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",\n    \"Undead Goblin (7E4L1): Worth $77, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",\n    \"Flying Human (8K9Y2): Worth $35, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",\n    \"Flying Human (8J8T0): Worth $94, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",\n    \"Shiny Dwarf (5E2Z1): Worth $42, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",\n    \"Flying Troll (1K1G7): Worth $71, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",\n    \"Shiny Troll (9X6C8): Worth $40, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",\n    \"Flying Elf (3H0R6): Worth $54, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\"\n)"

)
```

How do I make it print out the \n like this?

```
My Container contains 11 items
My Container: Total Value = $1096: (
    "Undead Goblin (8Q2U8): Worth $73, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Flaming Troll (5Y2V3): Worth $40, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Undead Human (2F9Z7): Worth $40, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Flying Elf (8G5V6): Worth $99, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Undead Orc (3P9B1): Worth $10, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Undead Goblin (6R5C1): Worth $93, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Stone Giant (3E4O0): Worth $1, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Stone Goblin (3A6T4): Worth $30, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Shiny Troll (8S3I1): Worth $77, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Flying Orc (4F6F9): Worth $65, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:54 +0800",
    "Dublicate Container: Total Value = $568: (
        "Flying Elf (1P5F4): Worth $29, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",
        "Shiny Elf (3R2Q6): Worth $88, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",
        "Shiny Dwarf (4X7P8): Worth $38, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",
        "Undead Goblin (7E4L1): Worth $77, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",
        "Flying Human (8K9Y2): Worth $35, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",
        "Flying Human (8J8T0): Worth $94, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",
        "Shiny Dwarf (5E2Z1): Worth $42, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",
        "Flying Troll (1K1G7): Worth $71, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",
        "Shiny Troll (9X6C8): Worth $40, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\",
        "Flying Elf (3H0R6): Worth $54, recorded on 2013-04-21 13:17:58 +0800\"
    )"
)
```

Appreciate all help! Thanks!

Comment: The \n is automatically added when I call NSLog(@"%@," subItems);
I don't know how to print out all array items within subItems with the -(NSString *) description method

Answer (score 1):

When you print log, you can add \n\r to what you print.
For example

```
NSLog(@"This is the first Line \n\r This is the Second Line");
```

Will print:

This is the first Line
This is the Second Line

So try to use this feature to break the line whenever you want.

Comment: I can't use NSLog because the printing is done in the description.

    - (NSString *)description
    {
        NSString *descriptionString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", subItems];
        return descriptionString;
    }

Comment: So Insert those tags to the description:
    NSString *descriptionString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: Total Value = $%d: %@ \n\r", [self containerName], [self valueInDollars], subItems];

Comment: I just tried as suggested, it doesn't work. It's the last %@ itself that has ten lines in it.